# Unknown warning group '-Wmaybe-unintialized' Mac OS Sierra

Tags: c++, clang, pragma, macos-sierra, libc++

When trying to compile my software in Mac OS Sierra I run into an issue regarding unknown pragmas (See snippet below). According to a colleague, the software is able to compile in Mac OS X Yosemite with the same clang version (4.2.1). The compiling flags used are: `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`. Using `stdlibc++` is not an option as it does not include `std::shared_ptr`.

```
error: unknown warning group '-Wmaybe-uninitialized', ignored
  [-Werror,-Wunknown-pragmas]
                    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"
```

Here is a print out of `g++ --version`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Unsure where to take it from here, any input is much appreciated.

Comment: On macOS the standard compiler is Clang, which is *mostly* compatible with GCC. The command `g++` is just an alias for `clang++`. If you need GCC specific behavior (like the pragma you show) then I suggest conditional compilation for those parts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Someprogrammerdude. Okay, the software is compiled using `cmake`, where both me and my colleague are using the same `cmake` config while his works and mine does not. Is there any significant difference between Yosemite and Sierra in terms of clang versions and libraries that might interfere with `'-Wmaybe-uninitialized'` and making it fail while compiling?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of writing

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"
```

you should do

```
#if !defined(__has_warning) || __has_warning("-Wmaybe-uninitialized")
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"
#endif
```

Comment: Doing this, gives me an error in the preprocessor `error: missing binary operator before token "("`

Comment: Worked fine in case of "-Wpsabi" error on GCC 8.3.0.